# How to install stripped version of GTK (without *dbg files)?

Tags: raspbian

I am installing PiScope:
http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/piscope.html

there it is mentioned:
**"If you edit the list of packages to be downloaded and remove the *-dbg packages only 134MB of additional SD space is needed."**

Can some one guide on how to filter the list to remove dbg files?

`apt-get install gtk+-3.0` is installing all files.

Comment: Only solution found is:
(http://askubuntu.com/questions/74523/how-can-i-install-a-package-without-installing-some-dependencies)
There is a warning for this one too that it is for experts.
I am a novice user.

Answer (score 1):

Raspbian *doesn't* by default install those, so you have nothing to worry about.

```
> apt-cache search gtk+-3.0
[...]
libgtk-3-0 - GTK+ graphical user interface library
libgtk-3-0-dbg - GTK+ libraries and debugging symbols
```

Look, two separate packages.  I don't have either of them installed, but if I try `apt-get install libgtk-3-0`, it concludes with:

```
25 upgraded, 15 newly installed, 0 to remove and 21 not upgraded.
Need to get 18.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 12.6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
```

So perhaps not even "134MB of additional SD space".

---

If you want to compile software linking the library (as opposed to just use software that was pre-compiled linking to it), you need the additional `-dev` package (this is true for all libraries).  That just contains a few minor bits and pieces (FYI: C header includes and package-config files) and does not add anything to the installed size.  It will pull in the main library as a dependency, so:

```
apt-get install libgtk-3-dev
```

Should provide everything you need GTK+ 3.0 wise.

Comment: I'm not sure if libgtk-3-0 (rather than gtk+-3.0) is enough to allow you to build from source (no need to install anything if using a pre-built binary).

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
I will check it later today & update..

Comment: Reply from Joan helped. I am not compiling the source. Instead i tried running files from the package & was able to execute them without compiling. I am a novice user with no programming knowledge. So i was unable to check that initially.

Comment: @joan There is no `gtk+-3.0` as a package in raspbian; try `apt-cache search gtk | grep ^gtk` (all packages with names that begin `gtk`) and you'll see what I mean.  It is just a library, as per the description above ("GTK+ graphical user interface library"), that's all that GTK is: a library.  I did not pay close enough attention to the question but you are right, "install" here includes compiling, I've edited in a paragraph about this.

Comment: @AmandeepSingh It appears to me from the pigpio page you do need to compile it and so need the `-dev` package (read the paragraph I added above).  This is pretty normal with 3rd party stuff on linux and is not complicated (it's all automated).

Comment: @goldilocks I must admit I built it with Debian rather than Raspbian.  piscope can be used as a pre-built image.  pigpio itself does need to be built but only uses standard libraries (and does not use GTK).  The information was current at the time I wrote it.  I'll have a look to see what has changed and consider rewording the description.

Comment: @joan Whoops, just noticed Amandeep added her own answer (q.v).

Comment: @goldilocks and joan - Right, I was 

"no need to install anything if using a pre-built binary" form Joan helped. I found pre-compiled executable file & was able to execute it properly.I ran it on my ubuntu Laptop over LAN.

Thank you for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to manually edit the list of files to be downloaded.

sudo apt-get install gtk+-3.0

Say No to download/install.

On screen will be a list of files which would be installed.

Cut & paste that list to an editor.

Manually delete the dbg files.

You should end up with one long line will all the packages needed.  To the start of the line add sudo apt-get install.  Save the file as xxx.

Then enter the command

source xxx

The presented size of download should be much smaller.  If so, say Yes to download/install.

Comment: Thank you for the reply.
I will check it later today & update..

Comment: Tried this but it was consuming atleast 1300MB space.

Comment: @Amandeep Singh May I ask which operating system you are using?  e.g. Raspbian, Fedora, etc., or perhaps this was for a laptop/desktop?

Comment: I am using Raspbian..  now i am running it on ubuntu laptop.

Comment: @Amandeep Singh I was just speculating.  The packages bundled with a distribution vary.  I was wondering if that was why your figures were much larger than mine.  Thanks.

Comment: Yes I think so. Any how the issue is resolved now without installing the packages as I am able to execute the precompiled executable as per your initial comment on 25th Oct. Thank you.